# Mixing Websockets and REST

Tags: django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm writing a RESTfull api, where for example user can create new threads or new posts in a thread. This is where I would use normal POST request. My API also allows users to send messages to each other. And when a user receives a message I want notification in browser, this is where I would use websockets instead of polling every few seconds.

My questions are

- Since I already have open connection with websocket where messages will come, should I also use this connection to send messages, create new threads or posts?
- Can I use POST request for creating messages and websockets to receive them in realtime and GET request to get history of messages? Is this good practice?
- I'm using django rest framework, which handles validation of fields for me, how would I handle validation if I create resource using websocket instead of normal POST request.

I'm farily new in developing a RESTfull API, and I have only started developing with websockets. Sorry for any stupid questsions that may seem so logical for you :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Since I already have open connection with websocket where messages
>   will come, should I also use this connection to send messages, create
>   new threads or posts?

It depends. You want to use regular HTTP POST if you are using a CQRS approach and your writes are being handled by different boxes than your reads; or if you have to provide compatibility for external callers that may not support WebSockets.

> Can I use POST request for creating messages and websockets to receive
>   them in realtime and GET request to get history of messages? Is this
>   good practice?

It sounds reasonable. You would get REST compatibility and WebSocket as an enhancement. What I do is to use WebSockets for enhancing the REST API. Some operations are in both parts, for example "autocompletes" that are essentially a quick succession of calls and belong to the read model can be done both ways, however the downside is that I cannot take advantage of the builtin output cache and I have to implement my own cache for them.

> I'm using django rest framework, which handles validation of fields
>   for me, how would I handle validation if I create resource using
>   websocket instead of normal POST request.

I do not do django, but I guess you can somehow hook into that validation yourself and invoke it in your message object once deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your 3rd question, the most basic solution would look like

```
def ws_create_item(message):
    data = json.loads(message['text'])
    serializer = ItemSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

Where `ItemSerializer` is just your usual DRF serializer and `ws_create_item` is a receiving WebSocket consumer.